# Sapper/svelte3 session not synchronizing without page reload

Tags: session, sapper, svelte-3

I'm having trouble getting Sapper to synchronize session changes made in my server-side routes without a pageload. My example scenario is that I load my app with no user in the session, my server-side login route sets the user to the session, and I use `goto` to got to the dashboard.

The problem is that the `session` argument in the dashboard's preload function isn't populated. If I use `window.location.href = '/dashboard'`, it is, because it's running through Sapper's [page_handler](https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper/blob/9e70e68c0cc0865c76cfcfc23b3525e051c15e20/runtime/src/server/middleware/get_page_handler.ts). But if I do a client-only redirect, Sapper isn't sending the updated session to the client.

Any way around this? Am I using my tools wrong?

Note: I'm using connect-pg-simple and express-session, setting up sapper like this: `sapper.middleware({session: (req, res) => req.session.public})`.

Comment: Have a look at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58002360/sapper-session-not-setting-properly-in-production-build-without-page-reload/60222401#60222401

Answer (score 2):

I found my answer in the [Sapper docs](https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#Stores)

> `session` contains whatever data was seeded on the server. It is a writable store, meaning you can update it with new data (for example, after the user logs in) and your app will be refreshed.

Reading between the lines, this indicates that your app has to manually synchronize your session data.

The solution here is to manually sync the session data to the client, either with a webhook connection, a response header, or a key in the response data.

I've got a decorator I use to create a server route handler, in which I add the session data to the response. Here's a simplified version:

```
const createHandler = getData => (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({data: getData(req.body), session: req.session.public})
}
```

Obviously there's more to it than that, e.g. error handling, but you get the idea. On the client, I wrap `fetch` in a helper function that I always use anyway to get my json, set the correct headers, etc. In it, I look at the response, and if there's a `session` property, I set that to the session store so that it's available in my `preload`s.

```
import {stores} from "@sapper/app"

const myFetch = (...args) => fetch(...args).then(r => r.json()).then(body => {
  if (body.session) stores().session.set(body.session)

  return body.data
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I kind of understand your answer but I can't get my preload to pass the data. Do you mind if you post an example of your preload "<script context="module"> export async function preload() {}   to see how you set session in the stores() ? It's a big issue and I see more than one post requesting help and no one is helping. It seems like rich was the only one answering here and we need a workable example.

Comment: Unfortunately, I wasn't able to get preload working (session was part of the problem, there was something else I think), so I have no working examples.

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply, after your session status changes *from the front end* (user just logged in, or you just invalidated his login), you should update the session store on the front end.

```
<script>
  import { goto, stores } from '@sapper/app';
  const { session } = stores();

  const loginBtnHandler = () => {

    const req = await fetch('/api/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      credentials: 'same-origin', // (im using cookies in this example)
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ ........ })
   });

   if (req.ok) {
     // here is where you refresh the session on the client right after you log in
     $session.loggedIn = true; // or your token or whatever

     // next page will properly read the session
     goto('/');

     return;
   }

   ...

  }
</script>
```