# Sapper session not setting properly in production build without page reload

Tags: javascript, node.js, svelte, sapper

I'm working on a project using Sapper, and been struggling with something for a bit now – can't quite figure it out. I'm using Polka for my server (it was included with the [`sveltejs/sapper-template#rollup`](https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper-template) template so I went with it), and `cookie-session` for my session middleware.

Here is my Polka configuration, where I [seed session data](https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs#Seeding_session_data) also:

```
polka()
  .use(
    compression({ threshold: 0 }),
    sirv('static', { dev }),
    cookieSession({ 
      name: 'session', 
      keys: [
        '6e818055-d346-4fcb-bf56-4c7d54cb04ab', 
        '60f3e980-6e9c-460d-8ea7-af1fffbdb92f'
      ]
    }),
    sapper.middleware({
      session: (req, res) => ({
        user: req.session.user
      })
    })
  )
  .listen(PORT, err => {
    if (err) console.log('error', err);
  });
```

When a user logs in, it's handled in `routes/login.js` essentially some profile info and tokens get set on `session.user` and the request is redirected back to the root path. I'm using `@polka/send-type` to respond. See below:

```
req.session.user = { 
  accessToken: access_token,
  name: first_name,
  pic: picture.data.url
};
send(res, 302, '', {
  Location: appUrl
});
```

There, I have a  preload module for `routes/index.svelte` checks if `session.user` exists, and if so redirects to dashboard:

```
<script context="module">
  export async function preload(page, session) {
    const { user } = session;

    if (user) {
      return this.redirect(302, "dashboard");
    }
   }
</script>
```

This all works fine in dev, but when I `npm run build` and build for production it doesn't so well. It seems like the `session.user` isn't getting populated after the redirect in `login.js`.

The `session` object that I get in `preload` doesn't have `session.user` set after login, and vice versa on logout where `session.user` is simply set to null and the client is redirected to the root, `session.user` is still populated.

If I refresh the browser, `session.user` is in the correct state. Without a refresh – if I just logged out I can click around as if I were logged in, and if I had just logged in nothing happens as `session.user` is `undefined`.

Just not sure why it'd work on the dev build but not in production. Given that the `session.user` state is correct on browser refresh, I'm guessing it's not an issue with the cookie middleware configuration. Seems like I'm missing something else. Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Sapper does indeed handle the cache headers differently for dev and production environment. That's why you are experiencing it this way.

But there is a simple solution by changing the sapper.middleware function:

```
    sapper.middleware({
      session: (req, res) => {
        res.setHeader('cache-control', 'no-cache, no-store')
        return { user: req.session.user }
      }
    })
```

This sets the cache-control as you want it.